# SQL Server 0x0004005 "Unspecified error"

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic

This is a system/setup that has been working just fine for years. We have the web server on one box, SQL Server 2000 on a different one. Suddenly, we're getting the following error:

```
Provider (0x0004005) 
Unspecified error
(path to file), line 61
```

where line 61 has the RS.Open... stuff.

I had just modified a table (added a column) when this showed up, but otherwise we hadn't changed anything.

Anybody have any ideas? I'm very much just the web weenie, I don't know if I'm even providing the necessary/useful information...

Comment: At the moment, this is looking like it might be a hardware failure, namely the switch between the two servers. (We can ping the SQL box from the IIS box, but not the other way around.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, but it turned out to be something you couldn't have helped with: the switch between the two servers died, and this was just one of the symptoms. Among other things, the bad switch meant that the SQL server couldn't "see" the users/groups defined on the other server.

For what it's worth, the one datum that might be useful to other people experiencing this particular "unspecified error" is that it has *something* to do with SQL permissions. It might be a side-effect of the true problem, like it was in our case, but at least it's something to look at.

Comment: That's a side effect.  That particular error number is like the "junk drawer" of SQL Server - all kinds of stuff can trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that being a file not found or access denied error.  Not sure why it would suddenly stop working offhand.

Have you tried running the query manually?

Does it fail every time (ie reliably)?

Comment: The server looks fine via the administrative tools - Enterprise Manager gives no sign that anything might be wrong, etc. But every single page of the site gives that singularly useless error message, always on the first line that tries to open a database connection.

Comment: And you can run a normal query fine as the same user?

Do any of the app pages not use the DB?  Do they work?

Essentially we're trying to determine is the issue on the app / web server?  The connection itself?  Any external connection to the DB?   etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its failing at the point where ADODB opens the record set *RS.Open* My guess is were a table column is referenced by number & not by name. Remove the column you added & see if it fixes the issue.

Would also help if you should show us what is around line 61 on the page you are calling.  You'll need to fix the code in order to be able to add the column without the error, although a question like that would be more appropriate on stackoverflow

Comment: The error was coming up on every page that accessed the database, and for every table.